# Include const Array in Async Await NodeJS

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I need to make "async await" work in the following array so that the rest of the code can be executed.

```
listArray = [1520,1320,1560,5091] //dont move array
}).on("close", async () => {
    const codeFormat = await `array[${listArray.map((v) => `'${v}'`).reduce((r,v) => `${r},${v}`)}]`

    const first = await app.db.raw(`
        SELECT distinct t.code
            from table AS t
            where not exists (select 1 from unnest(${codeFormat}) el where t.code = el)
    `)
    const second = await app.db.raw(`
        select code
            from unnest(${codigosFormatadoArquivo}) code 
            where not exists (select 1 from tableName as t where t.code = code
    `)
    console.log('first.rows',first.rows)
    console.log('second.rows',second.rows)

    return resolve({dados, footer, header})
})`
```

In the current way, it just executes the second "const segundo" query, the first cannot be executed.

Comment: What is this `on.close` event and where it is coming from? Also, where is `resolve` coming from?

Comment: @goto1 ```on.close``` comes from ```readInterface.on('l', (l) => {```

Comment: So what is the problem that you're facing? Are you saying that `second` doesn't wait for `first` to execute?

Comment: @goto1 that's right, apparently you can't use async await with "map"

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "with map". I am not seeing you using `async/await` inside of a callback of the `map` method anywhere in your code.

Comment: @goto1     the line where I declare the 'map' constant, its execution is not being completed      ```const codeFormat = `array`...```

Comment: @goto1 I had forgotten to put it in the example, I already corrected it. "Await" does not work, however if I comment on the second query, the first is executed.

Comment: Why do you have to `await` for that to complete? It looks like `codeFormat` is just a `string`, not a `Promise`? `await` only works on `Promise`s.

Comment: @goto1 How can I refactor the code so that both "queries" only work after "codeFormat"?

Comment: Just get rid of the `await` from the `codeFormat`. There's no need for it to be there since `codeFormat` is a string, not a `Promise` that will resolve asynchronously.

Comment: @goto1 I had already done this, but it didn't work

Comment: The code you have above, assuming that you get rid of that `await` and fix the `resolve({dados, footer, header})` part (there's no `resolve` function anywhere in your code), should work fine. I think you're not showing all the relevant code, so it's impossible for me to tell what the problem is.